# How to inherit a class globally in the image recipe - yocto

Tags: yocto

In the Yocto build I can able to inherit a class globally to all recipes from local.conf adding

```
INHERIT += "<class-name>"
```

For this I need to edit the local.conf manually before the build. How to inherit the class globally for all recipes from image recipe (.bb) tried adding "inherit  as mentioned in [Yocto bitbake user manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.1/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#inherit-directive) but that doesn't work it results in build error.

Comment: there is recipe metadata and global config metadata, image is just a recipe so you can not inherit something in image and expect it to be propagated to other recipes, simply not going to work that way, all you can do in images is use image features to design the content of image based on some global distro features. The local.conf way is right. please keep doing it

Comment: Give us more information about the  <class-name>. Are you sure to want to inherit from ALL recipes ?